# OUT or INOUT argument for routine db is not a variable

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I created a procedure with out parameter in MYSQL. Its working fine while am calling through query. My problem is, I want to add this procedure in dot net DataTable. ServerExplorer-->RightClick--> AddTableAdaptor -->use Existing Stored Procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_OUTLETCREATION;
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_OUTLETCREATION(
IN SP_OutletId  smallint,
IN SP_OutletName varchar(20),
out SP_MSG varchar(50)
)...

I got the error 

OUT or INOUT argument 3 for routine xxx is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
```

I am using the MYSQL Connector Net 6.3.6. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you post the relevant C# code please? One thing to check is when adding the parameter that you that you set `.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: My Problem is Could not add the procedure in DataAdapter.